# OpenVPN client only for incoming connections

Tags: vpn, routing, port-forwarding, openvpn, raspberry-pi

In my home, I have a Raspberry PI that I want to make accessible over the Internet, but my ISP blocks port forwarding. So I signed a VPN service that allows port forwarding. I configured the Raspberry PI to automatically connect to the VPN, added a port on the VPN service dashboard, and everything worked as expected.
However, I'd like to use VPN only for incoming connections, with Raspberry PI traffic continuing through my ISP's gateway.
I've tried the solutions outlined [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway). By doing it, VPN connects normally, traffic continues to go through the default gateway (not VPN), but the incoming connection stops working.
Is there any way to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: It will not work, because the source IP address of the packet sent from RPi will be different from the destination IP address of packets received by RPi. So it is not possible to, for example, make a TCP connection.

Comment: @KrzysztofSawicki In fact, your comment has helped me come up with a solution. I added an answer to the question explaining what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krzysztof Sawicki's comment helped me to come up with a solution. In the OVPN file, I added the lines:

```
route-nopull

route 170.171.172.3 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
route 10.1.1.0      255.255.255.0   vpn_gateway

route 190.189.188.1 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway # my work
route 190.189.188.2 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway # another place
route 190.189.188.3 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway # another website
```

- The first line causes the OpenVPN client to not add the default routes.
- 170.171.172.3 is the IP of the VPN, which I want to always traffic through the default gateway.
- 10.1.1.0 is the VPN subnet, which I want to always traffic through the VPN gateway.
- 190.189.188.1 and 190.189.188.2 are locations that can access Raspberry PI remotely.
- 190.189.188.3 is any website I want to traffic through the VPN gateway

In conclusion: it really is not possible to expose a port to the entire Internet. However, it is possible to expose this port to specific locations. And that solution worked for me.

Comment: Good to know that I've helped a bit :-)